# Largest continuous sum in an array explanation

Tags: python-3.x

```
    def large_cont_sum(arr):

        if len(arr) == 0:
            return 0

        max_sum = current_sum = arr[0]

        for num in arr[1:]:

            current_sum = max(current_sum+num, num)                
            max_sum = max(current_sum, max_sum)

        return max_sum

large_cont_sum([1,2,-1,3,4,10,10,-10,-1])
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this problem and have been trying to find out how he got `29` and idk what `current_sum = max(current_sum+num, num)` and `max_sum = max(current_sum, max_sum)` means.

I know that the for loop starts at the second number and adds the first and second which gives `3` for current sum and compares it to the num which is `2` and returns the max which would mean `3` is the highest and then wouldn't max also take the current sum `3` and compare it to max number?

The problem is is the `max_sum` still 1 or is it currently `3` now and wouldn't that mean it would be `(3,3)` and the max sum returns `3` and then repeat so if 3 is the `current_sum` you add `- 1` and now have `2` and now the `current_sum` is `2` and it compares it to `-1` and `2` is higher and repeat?

I just don't understand.

Comment: What do you define as largest continuous sum? What answer would you expect for this data?

Comment: Add a sum that is like 1,2,3,4 = 10

Comment: So what is your expected answer for the data `[1,2,-1,3,4,10,10,-10,-1]`

Comment: The sum of `[1,2,-1,3,4,10,10]` *is* 29.

Comment: This is a problem of dynamic programming. Try search for it